# Fast correlation solution for pearson, kendall in R

Tags: r, performance

When I need to speed up the `cor(..., method="kendall")`, I found [Fast correlation in R using C and parallelization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18964837/6088044). This can easily speed up the `pearson` correlation calculation by `cor()` in R.

But the `kendall` is actually the slower one. Then the fast alternative can be `cor.fk (x, y = NULL)`, which is way faster than the `cor(..., method="kendall")`.

Answer (score 1):

When bootstrap or very large matrix are involved, a very fast alternative can be `cor.fk (x, y = NULL)`.

It can be used as follows:

```
library(PAsso)
# import data -------------------------------------------------------------
data(ANES2016)
summary(ANES2016)

system.time(
  cor_matrix <- cor(ANES2016[, c("Prevote.num","PID")], method = "pearson")
)
# user  system elapsed 
#   0       0       0 

system.time(
  cor_matrix <- cor(ANES2016[, c("PreVote.num","PID")], method = "kendall")
)
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.19    0.00    0.19 

library(pcaPP)
system.time(
  cor.fk(ANES2016[, c("PreVote.num","PID")])
)

# user  system elapsed 
#   0       0       0
```

Comment: It's fast, but unfortunately it does not provide the p-value like `cor.test` does.